# wait for an async operation before requiring other modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

In my main.js, I am reading a file asynchronously. Once my file is loaded, I set some objects in `GLOBAL` namespace and use them in my `require`d modules (using `GLOBAL` namespace or not is a different story, I am using it anyway).

My `require`d module immediately expects that variable to exist at the time of loading. So how do I make it wait till my file reading is complete in the main.js? Do I simply require module in the callback of `readFile`? Or there's a better way to do it?

example:

```
fs.readFile('./file', function (data) {
    // do something

    GLOBAL.obj = data;
});

require('./module.js');
```

module.js

```
obj.someFunction();
```

Comment: FYI, this is a poor design pattern.  If a module requires some external state, then the module should expose a constructor function and you should call that constructor when the state is available.  Then, you can `require()` the module at any time and finish initializing it by calling the constructor (and passing that state to the constructor) when you have that state.

Comment: Great! I was expecting suggestion like this. I wasn't very happy `require`ing modules like this. Thanks, I'll follow this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gut feeling of disliking that solution is understandable. (Your stomach is right). The proper way of cleaning this up (and you should take the time – future-you will thank you for it):

- go through every one of your ten modules
- for each one go through all the functions it exports
- for each function figure out, what globals they *actually* depend on.
- add those as arguments to the function.
  if they take a lot of arguments now, consider grouping them into objects, creating useful models.

if a bunch of functions all depend on the same set of variables, you can also consider creating a factory function

- create a function that takes the formerly global variables as arguments and wrap all of the module's code into that function.
- make that function the single export of your module. It serves as a factory function and creates the context for all the other functions in that module. It should return whatever the module exported before.

Example

```
// DB used to be a global
module.exports = function(DB) {
    function getUser(user, cb) {
        DB.get('user', db);
    }
    return {getUser: getUser};
};
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var module = require('module')(DB);
module.getUser(myUser, function(){}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just follow the rule #1 of async programming. Stuff that depends on callback happening must be executed in that callback. Since your `require` depends on the variable set in async, you can only use your `require` inside it:

```
fs.readFile('./file', function (data) {
    // do something

    GLOBAL.obj = data;
    require('./module.js');
});
```

Comment: I see. But there are like tens of modules that depend on `GLOBAL.obj`, should I `require` all of them in the callback? I figured this, but was wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: There is no better solution. If ten modules depend on something that happens in your callback, then they cannot get required (or used) outside that callback.